# Custom Object is not visible in Profile Tab Setting for System Admin

Tags: profile, object

I've created a custom object "package" in sandbox and deployed it to production.

I can create a record for "package" from record detail page. But object is not available on Tab. even When i Click on "Plus" icon, then also "package" object is not visible.

I'm a System Admin. I've checked the profile for system admin. Under Tab setting, I'm not able to see my custom object. But that object visible in the "Custom Object Permissions" for same profile.

System Admin Profile Custom Tab Setting:
[image]

System Admin Profile Custom Object Permission:
[image]

Comment: While creating tab , tab visibility to all profiles is giving ?

Comment: yes. In sandbox I can see for same.

Comment: and you are able to see tab in setup in production?

Comment: What happens when you try to create a new custom object tab for the custom object? Does it allow?

Comment: did you deploy the tab from the sandbox?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You have to add new TAB for that custom object as shown above. Then you will be able to see that custom object there